# User regex in Jmeter While loop

Tags: javascript, regex, jmeter

I have Jmeter while loop having regular expression extractor as post processor

Regular expression variable reference name is : `CFM`
It extracts: `(<\S+\s\S+)(\s+)(.*?hv_saw_)(.*?label1)("\s+\w+=")(Current Fiscal YTD)(.*?>)`

```
$4$ value is .*?label1
$6$  value is Current Fiscal YTD
```

Now I want to use $4 and $6 template in while loop but not able to do so..

Here is what i am doing:

`While loop :${__javaScript((${CFY_g4}.match(/.*?label1/) != "$4",))}`

I want unless my $4 template .match or .contains while loop continues to run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wooohuuu!!!

I researched further and came across Mozilla developers website that answers my questionrealted to fidning start and end of my variables. here is what i did:

My Javascript code inside while loop for $4 and $6 template:

`${__javaScript(! "${CFY_g4}".endsWith('label1') || (! "${CFY_g6}".match('Current Fiscal YTD')) )}`